# Integer only input Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am unsure on how to create an input box that only allows integers to be inputted. I have made a HTML version of the input but I need the same input type within JavaScript.

Here's my current HTML input

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57;">Amount</input>
```

Comment: _input type within JavaScript_ ? What is that ?

Comment: `<input type="number" />`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input

Answer (score 2):

You should change `type="text"` to `type="number"`. You might also be interested in setting values for the `min`, `max`, and `step` attributes as well.

```js
var input_element = document.getElementById('input');
var output_element = document.getElementById('output');

document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('input', function (event) {
    output_element.value = input_element.value;
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
    <label for="input">Input:</label>
    <input id="input" type="number" min="0" max="10" step="2" />

    <br />

    Output: <output id="output" for="input"></output>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove that up/down button from that number text box? May be OP requires that.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input` of type `number` and `step` attribute:

```
<input type="number" step="1">
```

This way the input can only take integer values.